# Beginner Python: how to update function to run multiple arguments through it

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have created a function that creates a pandas dataframe where I have created a new column that combines the first/middle/last name of an employee.  I am then calling the function based on the python `index(EmployeeID)`.  I am able to run this function successfully for one employee.  I am having trouble updating the function to be able to run multiple `EmployeeIDs` at once.  Let's say I wanted to run 3 employee IDs through the function. How would I update this function to allow for that?

```
def getFullName(EmpID):
    df = pd.read_excel('Employees.xls', 'Sheet0', index_col='EmployeeID', usecols=['EmployeeID','FirstName','MiddleName','LastName'] ,na_values=[""])
    X = df[["FirstName","MiddleName","LastName"]]
    df['EmployeeName'] = X.fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.LastName+", "+x.FirstName+" "+str(x.MiddleName), axis=1)
    if EmpID in df.index:
        rec=df.loc[EmpID,'EmployeeName']
        print(rec)
    else:
        print("UNKNOWN")
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Also, please add some sample data for us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want an argument to be able to consist of one or more records, you can use a list or tuple to represent it.

In practice for this example, because python is dynamically typed and because the [`.loc` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) of the pandas Dataframes can also take a list of values as arguments, you dont have to change anything. Just pass a list of employee ids as `EmpID`.

Without knowing how the EmpIDs look like, it is hard to give an example.

But you can try it out, by calling your function with

```
getFullName(EmpID)
```

and with

```
getFullName([EmpID, EmpID])
```

The first call should print you the record once and the the second line should print you the record twice. You can replace `EmpID` with any working id (see `df.index`).

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) I liked above has some minimal examples to play around with.

PS: There is a bit of danger in passing a list to `.loc`. If you pass an `EmpID` that does not exist, pandas will currently only give a warning (in future version it will give a `KeyError`. For any unknown EmpID it will create a new row in the result with NaNs as values. From the documentation example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])

df.loc[['viper', 'sidewinder']]
```

Will return

```
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```

Calling it with missing indices:

```
print(df.loc[['viper', 'does not exist']])
```

Will produce

```
                max_speed  shield
viper                 4.0     5.0
does not exist        NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add in an array of EmpIDs.

```
empID_list = [empID01, empID02, empID03]
```

Then you would need to use a for loop:

```
for empID in empID_list:
    doStuff()
```

Or you just use your fuction as the function in the for loop.

```
for empID in empID_list:
    getFullName(empID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this list of employee IDs:

```
empIDs = [empID1, empID2, empID3]
```

You need to then pass this list as an argument instead of a single employee ID.

```
def getFullName(empIDs):
    df = pd.read_excel('Employees.xls', 'Sheet0', index_col='EmployeeID', usecols=['EmployeeID','FirstName','MiddleName','LastName'] ,na_values=[""])
    X = df[["FirstName","MiddleName","LastName"]]
    df['EmployeeName'] = X.fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.LastName+", "+x.FirstName+" "+str(x.MiddleName), axis=1)
    for EmpID in empIDs:
        if EmpID in df.index:
            rec=df.loc[EmpID,'EmployeeName']
            print(rec)
        else:
            print("UNKNOWN")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way or another the `if EmpID in df.index:` will need to be rewritten. I suggest you pass a list called `employee_ids` as the input, then do the following (the first two lines are to wrap a single ID in a list, it is only needed if you still want to be able to pass a single ID):

```py
if not isinstance(employee_ids, list):
    employee_ids = [employee_ids]  # this ensures you can still pass single IDs

rec=df.reindex(employee_ids).EmployeeName.dropna()
```

In the old days, `df.loc` would accept missing labels and just not return anything, but in recent versions it raises an error. `reindex` will give you a row for every ID in `employee_ids`, with `NaN` as the value if the ID wasn't in the index. We therefore select the column `EmployeeName` and then drop the missing values with `dropna`.

Now, the only thing left to do is handle the output. The `DataFrame` has a (boolean) attribute called `empty`, which can be used to check whether any IDs were found. Otherwise we'll want to print the values of `recs`, which is a `Series`.

Thus:

```py
def getFullName(employee_ids):
    df = pd.read_excel('Employees.xls', 'Sheet0', index_col='EmployeeID', usecols=['EmployeeID','FirstName','MiddleName','LastName'] ,na_values=[""])
    X = df[["FirstName","MiddleName","LastName"]]
    df['EmployeeName'] = X.fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.LastName+", "+x.FirstName+" "+str(x.MiddleName), axis=1)

    if not isinstance(employee_ids, list):
        employee_ids = [employee_ids]  # this ensures you can still pass single IDs

    rec=df.reindex(employee_ids).EmployeeName.dropna()
    
    if rec.empty:
        print("UNKNOWN")
    else:
        print(rec.values)
```

(as an aside, you may like to know that a python convention is to use `snake_case` for function and variable names and `CamelCase` for class names)